# Thymeleaf - adding a part of a class name to classappend

Tags: css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm porting my application from JSP to Thymeleaf and i'm finding some problems when trying to use `classappend`

I have a div element which comes out if the operation was finished, in goor or bad way, so I usually add a `$css` value in my controller to append to the div class.
I cannot do it in Thymeleaf... I'm trying in this way

```
<div th:classappend="${css != null} ? alert alert-${css} alert-dismissible"
                            th:text="${msg != null} ? ${msg}">
                            <button title="close" type="button" class="close"
                                data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" aria-hidden="true">
                                x</button>
                            <strong th:text="${msg}"></strong>

                        </div>
```

${css} may be danger or success or any other Bootstrap text class...

I'm getting

```
Could not parse as expression: \"${css != null} ? alert alert-${css} alert-dismissible\
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your string concatenation:

```
<div th:classappend="*{css} ? 'alert alert-'+${css}+' alert-dismissable' : ''" th:text="*{msg} ? ${msg}: ''">
        <button title="close" type="button" class="close"
                data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        <strong th:text="${msg}"></strong>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it was not a problem of the third element, but of string concatenation! Change your answer, so i can accept it!!